# CKEditor5: add text when copying/cutting

Tags: events, ckeditor5

I am trying to capture the event when a user uses copy/cut so that I can add some text at the end of the text placed into the pastebin.

On a traditional textarea I would listen to the "copy" event.
On CKEditor the appropriate event seems to be [clipboardOutput](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:clipboardOutput).

But I am not clear now how to hook into CKEditor specific events and how to integrate into [output pipeline](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/clipboard.html#output-pipeline).

Would appreciate some pointers.

I have the editor running with this code:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), { } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

I tried adding this code below but it doesn't seem to trigger

```
ClassicEditor.model.document.on( 'clipboardOutput', (eventInfo, data) => {
    console.log(eventInfo, data);
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`clipboardOutput`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:clipboardOutput) event is fired on [`view.Document`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html) instance.

You could use [`UpcastWriter`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_upcastwriter-UpcastWriter.html) to modify [`view.DocumentFragment`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_documentfragment-DocumentFragment.html) provided in [`data.content`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_clipboard_clipboardpipeline-ClipboardOutputEventData.html#member-content) property of the event data.

Example:

```js
editor.editing.view.document.on( 'clipboardOutput', ( eventInfo, data ) => {
    const writer = new UpcastWriter( editor.editing.view.document );

    const paragraph = writer.createElement( 'p', null, [
        writer.createText( 'foobar' )
    ] );

    writer.appendChild( paragraph, data.content );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting a "UpcastWriter is not defined" exception but it seems like this is expected: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/202

Comment: Do you integrate a build of CKEditor or import it from source? When from a build you'll indeed need to go an extra mile to get an access to UpcastWriter.

Comment: I used https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ to create the build. But I have the same issue when I use the standard build:
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.4.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

When using the online-builder, is there a way to include UpcastWriter?